# trigger jquery only a certain screen min-width

Tags: jquery

I have this code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            $("#inslist").addClass("fadeoutnow");
        }

        if (scroll <= 100) {
            $("#inslist").removeClass("fadeoutnow");
        }

        if (scroll >= 315) {
            $(".page-id-556 .vc_col-sm-4").addClass("floatcontact");
        }

        if (scroll <= 315) {
            $(".page-id-556 .vc_col-sm-4").removeClass("floatcontact");
        }
    });
});
```

I want it to work only on certain screen widths, basically min-width 
I have tried adding a line with the following in different parts of the code, but it doesn't work. I'm not a specialist in javascript, Im learning at the moment.
and the PHP notions I have doesn't work here.

```
if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {
}
```

I have tried to add

```
if (scroll >= 315) & ((window).width() >= 1024){ {
$(".page-id-556 .vc_col-sm-4").addClass("floatcontact");
```

}

Comment: First of all, does your script works (without thinking about device width) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the window width on the `resize()` event, otherwise the layout will only reflect the width when it was loaded. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
        var $win = $(window);
        var scroll = $win.scrollTop();
        var winWidth = $win.width();

        if (winWidth <= 1024)
            return;

        $("#inslist").toggleClass("fadeoutnow", scroll >= 100);
        $(".page-id-556 .vc_col-sm-4").toggleClass("floatcontact", scroll >= 315);
    });
});
```

Note also the simplified use of `toggleClass()` with the boolean parameter based on the `scroll` position.

Comment: It worked perfectly. I will study the code now to be able to use this solution in other situations. If you can point me more reference sites / readings i would really appreciate. thank you. I've learned a lot today.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're referring to jQuery, then the documentation is the best reference: http://api.jquery.com. If you mean JS itself, try MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your code to the resize event of the window :

```
    function activate() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 100) {
                $("#inslist").addClass("fadeoutnow");
            }

            if (scroll <= 100) {
                $("#inslist").removeClass("fadeoutnow");
            }

            if (scroll >= 315) {
                $(".page-id-556 .vc_col-sm-4").addClass("floatcontact");
            }

            if (scroll <= 315) {
                $(".page-id-556 .vc_col-sm-4").removeClass("floatcontact");
            }
     }


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(window).on('resize scroll', function(){
      if ($(window).width() >= 1024)
         activate()
   }
});
```

Comment: What happens if the page starts > 1024, but is resized to be less? ;)

Comment: Then you need to write a 'disable' function ;)